# Does anyone know what this Magento function does : function __('text')

Tags: magento-1

Does anyone know what this Magento function does : function  `__('text')` ?

I guess it echoes text, but it is not a php native function. Using Sublime text, is there a way to find in which class it defined ? I use Magento CE 1.8.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044584/how-does-magento-translate-works

Answer (score 4):

`__` is the translation function.
It translates the text received as a parameter if if finds a translation or it returns the text as it is if there is no translation.

The function not defined in any class.
It is defined in the [`functions.php`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php#L93) file
The `functions.php` file is included in [`Mage.php`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/Mage.php#L50) so it is available for all requests.

Comment: @Marius is the technical name for this function "translation" or do we call it something else?

Comment: Not sure if it's the technical name. I have been calling it like that since the beginning.